# how to subtract AS value from AS value in a extra AS column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables( `tbl1` and `tbl2` ) in my MySQL database. Now, I have wrote a query like following to generate summation of in_quantity and out_quantity where `serialno = AAA1` -

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT 
        #GROUP_CONCAT(in_quantity), 
        SUM(in_quantity) GP FROM stockin WHERE serialno = 'AAA1'
) A,
(
    SELECT 
        #GROUP_CONCAT(out_quantity),
        SUM(out_quantity) SOP FROM stockout WHERE serialno = 'AAA1'
) B
```

This query output like below-

```
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
|  800 |  740 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I need following results-

```
+------+------+------+
| A    | B    | C    |
+------+------+------+
|  800 |  740 |   60 |
+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can i write this in my query? I have checked several thread at stackoverflow.com. But, none where are about `(AS A - AS B) = AS C`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use your "A" "B" query as a subquery :

```
SELECT q.A, q.B, q.A-q.B as C FROM
  (SELECT 
  (
    SELECT 
        #GROUP_CONCAT(in_quantity), 
        SUM(in_quantity) GP FROM stockin WHERE serialno = 'AAA1'
  ) A,
  (
    SELECT 
        #GROUP_CONCAT(out_quantity),
        SUM(out_quantity) SOP FROM stockout WHERE serialno = 'AAA1'
  ) B
  --following code
) q
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks dude @Raphael Althaus... Please give me up vote in this question.